# .NET framework is not actually on 4?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, .net

I am writing a powershell script to run on a windows server 2008-r2 box running powershell v2, and it requires the ability to zip files. To do that, I need to have this line of code to import the assembly:

```
add-type -path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"
```

However, when I run the code, it errors with:

```
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.IO.Compressi
on.FileSystem.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runt
ime and cannot be loaded.
```

So I went to check what .NET version is installed using the registry method provided here: [Microsoft: How to determine which .NET Framework versions are installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx)

And sure enough I am on

```
378758 == .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on Windows 8, Windows 7 SP1, or Windows Vista SP2
```

And it even shows the install path as:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

Does anyone know what may be the issue here? Or what I can do as a workaround (**Without software updates/installs**).

Comment: Try `Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`

Comment: I received this error: "Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' could not be found."

Comment: Ok, try this path instead: `Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll"`

Comment: That path does not exist on my server.. I don't have a 'Reference Assemblies' folder in program files (x86)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ".NET Framework Version" setting in IIS actually do?](https://serverfault.com/questions/410757/what-does-the-net-framework-version-setting-in-iis-actually-do)